# c# asp.net problem with 'must declare the scalar variable'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently making a front end to display license information for my companies software audit but im no pro with sql or asp.net so iv ran into a bit of trouble. I'm trying to get a sum of how many licenses there are across several rows so i can put it in a text box, but im getting the error 'Must declare the scalar variable "@softwareID".'

```
SqlConnection con1 = Connect.GetSQLConnection(); 
        string dataEntry = softwareInputTxt.Text; 
        string result; 

        dataEntry = dataEntry + "%"; 
con1.Open(); 
        SqlCommand Mycmd1; 
        Mycmd1 = new SqlCommand("select sum(license_quantity_owned) from licenses where software_ID like @softwareID", con1); 
        MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@softwareID", dataEntry); 
        result = (string)Mycmd1.ExecuteScalar(); 
        licenseOwnedTxt.Text = result;
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

d'oh! Found it:

```
Mycmd1 ...
MyCmd ...
```

Two different commands!!!

You want:

```
Mycmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@softwareID", dataEntry);
```

(or assign `MyCmd` and `Mycmd1` to be the same thing)

---

I think it might already be the default, but you could try setting the `.CommandType` to `CommandType.Text` explicitly. Also, note that `AddWithValue` can cause more query-plans than necessary to be created; I would explicitly create the variable with a known size (the size of the column plus spare for the `%`). The existing string-concat should *already* ensure it isn't `null` (which is usually the problem).

Additionally, note that both `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` are `IDisposable` - both could be wrapped in `using` here.

Comment: oops, what an obvious mistake to make yet no-one including me spotted it haha, theres other commands i didnt bother copy pasting here... it works fine now thanks